# How to use readmore.js with foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Doesnt seem to work. Is there a fix? It seems readmore is expecting sections and artcles; however, foundation uses divs i.e. row and columns. How to fix?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and more info. In general you can use any tag with foundation grid.

Comment: If i add a foundation "row" div in the "container" div, it works. Once I add a "columns large-12" div in that row, foundation doesnt show the button and hide the offset correctly. It seems like a float issue. If i add a clear both div last in the container, it doesnt fix the issue. Foundation definitely doesnt work with readmore without customization. Does anyone have this customize example

Answer (score 0):

You can use any HTML5 tag with Foundation's grid. The default grid uses Flexbox, no floats and the styles are class based, not tag based.

Example:

```
<article class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="section medium-4 cell">
    <!-- your content -->
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Your example doesnt include readmore. This is not a foundation specific question - its readmore with foundation